# Calculate 2D point from projection matrix and 3D world point

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

i'm attempting to calculate a point on the image plane after stereo calibration using the projection matrix and some specific 3D world point.

Sensor: 2/3
w, h: 2448x2048

I'm using the following equation:

[image: formel.png]

```
    def draw_3d_point_on_img(self, K, R, t, X, im, cam=0):
        uv_hom = None
        print("K:\n", K)
        if cam == 0:
            P0 = compute_proj1_mtrx(K1=K)
            uv_hom = P0 @ X

        if cam == 1:
            P1 = compute_proj2_mtrx(K2=K, R=R, t=t.reshape(-1))
            uv_hom = P1 @ X

        if uv_hom is None:
            return im

        uv = np.array([uv_hom[0], uv_hom[1]]) / uv_hom[2]
        im = draw_circle(img=im, x=uv[0], y=uv[1])

        print("            World coordinate point X:", X)
        print("Homogeneous coordinate point uv_hom:", uv_hom)
        print("               Image plane point uv:", uv)
        return im


if __name__ == "__main__":
    im2_ = draw_projection_point(
        camera_matrix,
        R,
        T,
        X=np.array([1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0]),
        im=im2.copy(),
        cam=1,
    )
    cv2.imshow("draw the point", im2_)
```

Output:

```
K:
 [[3.54256103e+03 0.00000000e+00 1.25698372e+03]
 [0.00000000e+00 3.54188255e+03 1.09639913e+03]
 [0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00]]

Rt:
 [[ 0.9748454   0.02268535 -0.22172465  0.07601858]
 [-0.11580414  0.90154028 -0.4169107   0.12351445]
 [ 0.19043594  0.43210011  0.88148945  0.05658135]]


P2:
 [[ 3.69282420e+03  6.23507030e+02  3.22544774e+02  3.40422282e+02]
 [-2.01370865e+02  3.66690396e+03 -5.10184463e+02  4.99509420e+02]
 [ 1.90435941e-01  4.32100109e-01  8.81489448e-01  5.65813451e-02]] 

            World coordinate pont X: [1. 1. 0. 1.]
Homogeneous coordinate point uv_hom: [4.65675351e+03 3.96504252e+03 6.79117396e-01]
               Image plane point uv: [6857.06704825 5838.52297636]
```

I'm doing something wrong, because the point is not on the image plane. Any idee, what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You do not say what the image size is. Assuming the principal point K[:2,2] is centered, your image has ~ 2200 rows 2500 columns. You point X is far to the right and below the camera.

Comment: The image size is 2448x2048. The point is outside from the image plane, correct. The question is, what im doing wrong. The problem is mayby  in the stereo calibration.  because for the projection matrix in camera 2  i use the R and t_vec from the stereo calibration.